# How to use a SKScene as a SCNMaterial?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, scenekit

I am having a SKScene as a SCNMaterial that I want to apply on a SCNSphere. I want to add a point on the surface of the sphere, that should be partially visible even when it is on the other side of the sphere. So I want a double sided texture. But when I use `spherematerial.isDoubleSided = true` I get a whitish layer on top of my sphere. Not sure why this happens.

Here is my code:

```
    let surfacematerial =  SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 800, height: 400))
    surfacematerial.backgroundColor = SKColor.blue
    self.point.fillColor = SKColor.red
    self.point.lineWidth = 0
    self.point.position =  CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200)
    surfacematerial.addChild(point)

    let spherematerial = SCNMaterial()
        spherematerial.isDoubleSided = true
        spherematerial.diffuse.contents = surfacematerial

    let sphere = SCNSphere(radius: CGFloat(2))

        sphere.materials = [spherematerial]
        spherenode = SCNNode(geometry: sphere)
        spherenode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)
        spherenode.opacity = CGFloat(0.9)
```

Comment: That's because you only have one material set to the materials property of scene node.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not able to implement what you are trying to say in my code. Can you please show me some code ?

Comment: [spherematerial1, spherematerial2]